# How can I kick all members without a role in my discord server ? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to figure out a command to kick all members **without** a role in my discord server. I searched Google + this website and I found solutions that don't seem to work for me. Here's what I tried.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def noroleskick(ctx):
    server=ctx.message.server
    for member in tuple(server.members):
        if len(member.roles)==1:
            await bot.kick(member)

bot.run(token)
```

However, this didn't work, and here's the error:

```py
File "main.py", line 111, in noroleskick
    server=ctx.message.server
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'server'
```

I found this on Reddit. If this is no brainer, I sincerely apologize. I am a beginner at coding, so if you could go into detail I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message. To access the server, `discord.py` uses the term `guild`..

Comment: `ctx.message.guild` is what you are looking for. You can also just use `ctx.guild`

Comment: I applied ctx.message.guild to the code and I got no errors, but the bot didn't do anything either. I also changed if "len(member.roles)==1:" to 0 instead. I even tested a regular kick command on an alt to prove the bot is capable and it worked. There's around a thousand users in the server that I am attempting to kick, though.

Comment: @deezee Replace `await bot.kick(member)` with `await server.kick(member)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions

intents = discord.Intents.all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)

@bot.command()
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kicknorole(ctx: commands.Context):
    members = ctx.guild.members
        
    for member in members:
        if len(member.roles) == 1:
            await member.kick()
            print(member.name)
    await ctx.reply('Done!')

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Here is what I used. I was asked by a friend to kick all the users from their server with no roles. This worked for me. 762 members, hope it works for you!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `ctx.message.server` to `ctx.message.guild` or just `ctx.guild` and enable the members intent from the [discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and then use the following code to enable it in your script

```
from discord import Intents
intents = Intents()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)
```